# Can't find the correct regex pattern to get value between html tags

Tags: c#, regex

I can't find a way to gain the value inside this span:

```
                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
            &#36;0.15 USD           </span>
```

I tried with this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<span class=""market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"">(.*?)</span>");
Match match = regex.Match(result);
string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

But probably it doesn't match tabs or symbols...

Comment: Don't use regexes on HTML... [bad things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/945456) happen...

Comment: HTML is not a regular language. You need to use something else than regular expressions.

Comment: regular expressions are perfectly fine for the purpose of `web scraping` of a single value. No HTML Parsing library will help when the content of a page change anyway

Comment: I won't use regexes on HTML anymore... I promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the above comments you may be better off using the [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This will allow you to select the content of the span using XPath.

You can then use syntax such as

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(String.Format("http://sitecontainingspan.com"));

var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee']").InnerText;
```

This should load the page, find the span with the correct class and extract from it the value.

Comment: Do you know how to improve the download speed of the page? Do I have alternative? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but you could probably cache the page locally as a html file before you parse it.

Answer (score 2):

add `RegexOptions.Singleline` argument for your `Regex` constructor

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following minor change to your Regex...

```
<span class=""market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"">([\s\S]*?)</span>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to select the content of the span like this:
$(".market_listing_price").text() 
You can narrow it down further based on the position in the document, or you can select all the elements and manipulate them then.
Checkout http://jquery.com/ for further information